# How to show that a map is linear in $C^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, map-projections

Could someone tell me if I am on right way solving Problem b)?

Problem:

> Let $U,V\subset\mathbb C^n$ be two subspaces, such that $\mathbb C^n = U+V$ and further assume $U\cap V = \{0\}$.
>
> a) Show that every $x\in\mathbb C^n$ can be written as $x=x_U+x_V$ with $x_U\in U$ and $x_V\in V$ and that this decomposition is unique.
>
> b) Define $f : \mathbb C^n  → \mathbb C^n$,  $f(x) := x_U$. Show that $f$ is a linear map.
>
> $x_u$ is a Projection of $x$ onto $U$, where $U$ is a subspace of $C^n$

My thoughts:

> $f(x)  = \langle \lambda  , x_U\rangle = \lambda \cdot f(x)$
>
> $f(x) = (x+ y) = x_u + y_u= f(x) + f(y)$

Comment: What does $x_U$ mean?

Comment: Projection of x onto u where U is a subspace

Comment: And how do you define *that*?

Comment: Your function doesn't make sense.

Comment: @K.Y That function makes sense. The decomposition as sum of an element of $U$ and an element of $V$ is unique. This defines two projections over $U$ and $V$.

Comment: @Crostul  So its my solution right?

Comment: Your solution is not a solution. You have to use the previous informations to solve it. You cannot prove this siply by writing some formulas.

Comment: I only want to prove that it is a linear map

Comment: You seem to be obsessed with inner products. Coming from an engineering or physics background? There's no inner product needed here.

Comment: @Crostul I commented before the edits ;)

Answer (score 3):

You did not prove a).

Since $\mathbb{C}^n = U + V = \{ x_U + x_V \mid x_U \in U, x_V \in V\}$, we know that each $x\in\mathbb C^n$ can be written as $x=x_U + x_V$ with $x_U\in U$ and $x_V \in V$. Assume we have another such decomposition $x = x'_U + x'_V$. Then $x_U  - x'_U = x'_V - x_V$. The left hand side is an element of $U$, the right hand side an element of $V$. Since $U \cap V = \{0\}$, we see that $x_U  - x'_U = x'_V - x_V = 0$. This proves uniqueness.

Your proof of b) is not correct (although you probably had the right idea).

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and let $x = x_U + x_V, y = y_U +y_V$ be their unique decompositions. Then $\lambda x + \mu y = (\lambda x_u + \mu y_u) + (\lambda x_V + \mu y_V)$ is a decomposition of $\lambda x + \mu y$ and by uniqueness we see that

$$f(\lambda x + \mu y) = (\lambda x + \mu y)_U = \lambda x_u + \mu y_u = \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y) .$$